# React jest hook testing: waitFor internal async code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I have the following hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function useAsyncExample() {
  const isMountedRef = useRef(false);
  const [hasFetchedGoogle, setHasFetchedGoogle] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMountedRef.current) {
      isMountedRef.current = true;
      const asyncWrapper = async () => {
        await fetch("https://google.com");
        setHasFetchedGoogle(true);
      };
      asyncWrapper();
    }
  }, []);

  return hasFetchedGoogle;
}
```

With the following jest test (using msw and react-hooks testing library):

```
import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { rest } from "msw";
import mswServer from "mswServer";
import useAsyncExample from "./useAsyncExample";

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("using async hook", () => {
  beforeEach(() =>
    mswServer.use(
      rest.get("https://google.com/", (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.json({ success: ":)" }));
      })
    )
  );

  test("should should return true", async () => {
    const { result, waitFor, waitForNextUpdate, waitForValueToChange } = renderHook(() => useAsyncExample());

    // ... things I tried
  });
});
```

And I am simply trying to wait for the `setHasFetchedGoogle` call.

I tried multiple things:

```
await waitForNextUpdate(); // failed: exceeded timeout of max 5000 ms

await waitForValueToChange(() => result.current[1]); // failed: exceeded timeout of max 5000 ms

await waitFor(() => result.current[1])  // failed: exceeded timeout of max 5000 ms
```

The closest I have come so far is the with the following:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(global, "fetch");
// ...
await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
expect(spy).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith("https://google.com");
```

But even this ends right **before** the `setHasFetchedGoogle` call happens, since it only await the fetch.

Online I found plenty of examples for component, where you can `waitFor` an element or text to appear. But this is not possible with hooks, since I am not rendering any DOM elements.

How can I listen to internal async logic of my hook? I though the `waitForNextUpdate` has exactly that purpose, but it doesn't work for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest mocking `fetch` (I actually don't know if it's possible) I will try now.
Then you can asset the function invocation with expect.

Comment: @AvnerIsrael Isn't that basically what I am doing already with the spy?

Comment: I've managed to test a case very similar to yours with one difference. That is mocking the async function in the react hook.
Have you tried changing `Fetch` to `await new Promise.resolve()`?

Comment: @AvnerIsrael not sure what you mean by that. It's in general not really about the "fetch". I want to wait for a react state to update, thats the main goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turns out my example works as I wanted it to.

The problem is that in the real-world case I have, the custom hook is more complex and has other logic inside which uses setTimeouts. Therefore I had `jest.useFakeTimers` enabled.

Apparently `jest.useFakeTimers` doesn't work together with `waitForNextUpdate`.

[See more info](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/523#issuecomment-755246038)

I will now try to get my tests to work by enabling/disabling the fakeTimers when I need them

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your answer, you are using `jest.useFakeTimers`, but you are incorrect to say it doesn't work with `waitForNextUpdate` because it does.

Here is an example. I've modified your request to google to simply be an asynchronous event by waiting for two seconds. Everything should be the same with an actual mocked request though.

```js
const wait = (delay: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay))

function useAsyncExample() {
  const isMountedRef = useRef(false);
  const [hasFetchedGoogle, setHasFetchedGoogle] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMountedRef.current) {
      isMountedRef.current = true;
      const asyncWrapper = async () => {
        await wait(200);
        setHasFetchedGoogle(true);
      };
      asyncWrapper();
    }
  }, []);

  return hasFetchedGoogle;
}

// The test, which assumes a call to jest.useFakeTimers occurred in some beforeEach.
it('should should return true', async () => {
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useAsyncExample())

  expect(result.current).toBe(false)
  act(() => {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(200)
  })
  await waitForNextUpdate()
  expect(result.current).toBe(true)
})
```

Comment: I think because you switched out the fetch with a setTimeout, the behaviour is exactly different. Can you get this to work with a fetch too?

Comment: Both are returning a `Promise` so why would it not work with `fetch`? If you are using fake timers you have to advance them somehow. You can also `fetch.mockReturnValueOnce` and then `Promise.resolve` whatever you want and then wait for fetch to have been called, i.e. remove the fake timer usage (which you haven't shown yet).

Comment: They both return a promise, but one of them is made using a setTimeout, which jest will under the hood make some changes on how that works when using fake timers. Therefore the advanceTimersByTime will work. If you replace the `wait` in your example with a fetch (just pick and choose a public api if you dont have msw) it will not work anymore, as my example was exactly that

Comment: Why don't you show your complete code if you want more help? Are you mocking your `fetch` call appropriately? How can anyone know if you don't show the code?

Comment: My incomplete example was just the missing jest.useFakeTimers, which I added now. The google call is mocked using msw, which is already shown in the example. No need to show how the mswServer was setup, since that is just a setupServer call from msw.
So far disabling jest.useFakeTimers is the solution